# How quickly does a gas reach a uniform temperature in an enclosure?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, estimation

I'm just looking for ballpark figures and reasoning.

Suppose a gas (air) at STP was introduced into a 10cm diameter sphere of infinite heat capacity and conductivity at one degree above the gas. How long would it take for the bulk of the gas to come within (say) a milliKelvin of the enclosure temperature?

Comment: What have you done to try to figure it out yourself?

Comment: What have I done? Got a PhD student to run a simulation on the real system. The result seemed counterintuitive to me so I'm asking as a check.

Comment: Great, so I think you should add that into the question.

Comment: what was the result that the student got? Was it above or below expectations?

Comment: The temp reached equilibrium within 1 mK of the casing after less than 10 seconds. Top be fair, the real object is a stainless steel pipe with a 3mm/s gas flow and a diameter of 25mm. However, order of magnitude would likely still apply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One favorite calculation method for approximating diffusion (heat, mass, whatever) is to use the following pretty simple relation:
$$L^2 = C D t_c$$
in which you've got length (radius in this case), a constant dependent on geometry (6 for a sphere), diffusivity, and characteristic time.  Here you know all but $t_c$, for which you can easily solve (~21s).

Overall, the system is going to approach equilibrium as
$$T - T_{wall} = (T_{initial}- T_{wall})\,e^{-t/t_c}$$
So, after 7 or 8 time constants (160 s), you should be basically there.

N.B. the Rayleigh number of this problem is, initially, 13,000-110,000 (not to sure if I should use radius or diameter for $L$). So you'll have some convective mixing early on that'll hasten the process, but this effect will become increasingly weak as the system approaches equilibrium. So it'll reduce the time a bit.

Comment: That's not too far off given that this is an idealized case and the real one is a 25mm pipe. I just found it surprising that it happens so fast. It is also good news for our project since it results in a massive simplification of the technology.

Answer (score 1):

Since the object is small and spherical, and the temperature difference is small, I am going to assume there is no convection - meaning that you basically are asking about a conduction problem.

Thermal conductivity of air is 0.0257 W/m/K at 20 °C, and heat capacity is 1.005 kJ/kg/K

Details of the calculation (including an animation) are nicely shown in http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TransientCoolingOfASphere/ since the boundary conditions of this problem are the same as the one simulated there.